# Using a trigger to retrieve the last records of each ID

Tags: postgresql, triggers

This is my table :

```
ID    Last_modified_date     status
1     06-01-2013 17:05       New
1     06-02-2013 12:08       Assigned
2     07-03-2013 18:17       New
2     08-03-2013 15:12       Assigned
2     08-03-2013 18:05       Fixed
```

I need the following result

```
ID    Last_modified_date     status       Trigger
1     06-01-2013 17:05       New          False
1     06-02-2013 12:08       Assigned     True
2     07-03-2013 18:17       New          False
2     08-03-2013 15:12       Assigned     False
2     08-03-2013 18:05       Fixed        True
```

I can use this trigger to retrieve the last records of each ID.

Comment: I don't understand the that trigger column. Based on which information does it contain `true` or false`. And besides your usage of "trigger" is a bit confusing. A trigger is a piece of code that runs when something is changed in the database, it's not something that can be "used" in a SELECT statement.

Comment: I need to switch from true to false for each new record for a specific ID

Comment: How do you identify a "new record"? I don't really see the logic in the sample output.

Comment: I think what is meant is the latest modification for each ID number. There are two rows of ID=1, and only the latest one is marked "true"; likewise for the three rows with ID=2.

Answer (score 1):

this one will give you desired result, but I'm not sure that this is logic you want:

```
with cte as (
    select
        *,
        row_number() over(partition by id order by last_modified_date desc) as row_num
    from Table1
)
select
    id, last_modified_date,  status,
    case when row_num = 1 then 'True' else 'False' end as "Trigger"
from cte
order by id, last_modified_date asc
```

Or if you just want last rows for each id, you can use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (id)
    id, last_modified_date,  status
from Table1
order by id, last_modified_date desc
```

[**=> sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/a52e0/4)

**update**
If you need trigger, try something like this:

```
create or replace function tr_Table1_func()
returns trigger
as
$$
begin
    update Table1 as t set
        tr = t.last_modified_date > new.last_modified_date
    where t.id = new.id and t.tr = TRUE
    returning not tr into new.tr;

    new.tr = coalesce(new.tr, TRUE);

    return new;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;

create trigger tr_Table1
before insert on Table1
for each row execute procedure tr_Table1_func();
```

[**=> sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/b99ed/4)

Comment: The "trigger" "column" is completely superfluous. The OP said he wanted to use the "trigger" to retrieve the last-modified row for each ID. So I'd just use

    `with cte as (
      select
          *,
          row_number() over (partition by id order by last_modified_date desc) as row_num
      from Table1
    )
    select
        id, moddate, status
    from cte
    where rownum=1
    order by id asc`

That should do what the OP really seems to want.

Comment: @dcsohl yes, I'll add this to the answer, thanks. But since OP doesn't answering the questions it's really hard to know what he really wants. If my answer is correct, the word "trigger" should be removed from this page completely, this has nothing to do with triggers.

Comment: Im really soorryyy for this lateness. Ive juste seen your answers. What I really want, is to add a column to my source table. This column is a trigger or a flag that will be true for each new record for a specific ID and false for the old records.

Comment: @user2311028 do you really want it as a trigger? it could be calculated on the fly with row_number and it's relatively fast

Comment: Yes, I need to use the trigger. I need to detect each time that a new record in inserted, and put the old record to false and the new one to true. This solution is used only if i insert at one time the data.